# How to make text inside a grid stretch

Tags: html, css

So, i was making an auto-fill grid , which would move element to the next line if width reached 800px.
However, no matter what i did, my text inside a grid doesn't stretch

[image]

Here is my css:

```
   ul {
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(60px, 1fr));
       grid-template-rows: auto;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       text-align: center;
                
        li {
            margin: 0 10px;
            list-style-type: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
             adding: 5px;
            }
         }
```

Updated:

auto-fit could solve part of my problem,

however, i would like to make only [New one] and [Test two] stretch to fit one line, because i want these buttons to stretch to multiple lines if too many.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `auto-fit` instead.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 800px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(60px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ALL</li>
  <li>New One</li>
  <li>777</li>
  <li>Test two</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Or `float` instead of `grid`.

```css
ul {
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ALL</li>
  <li>New One</li>
  <li>777</li>
  <li>Test two</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>ALL</li>
  <li>New One</li>
  <li>777</li>
  <li>Test two</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>ALL</li>
  <li>New One</li>
  <li>777</li>
  <li>Test two</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>ALL</li>
  <li>New One</li>
  <li>777</li>
  <li>Test two</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i want every grid's width fit the text length, how could i do that?

Comment: In your case (width fit the text length), I think `float` will be better solution.